# Why the Angular ng-options value contains the value data type?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

Guys after I used the angular directive **ng-options** I got this result

```
<select name="users" id="users" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users" ng-model="user">
    <option value="number:1" label="Developers">Ahmed</option>
    <option value="number:2" label="Designers">Jon</option>
    <option value="number:3" label="HR">Astm</option>
    <option value="number:4" label="Doctor">Fady</option>
</select>


<select name="colors" id="colors" ng-options="color.code as color.name for color in colors" ng-model="color">
    <option value="string:ff0000" label="Developers">Red</option>
    <option value="string:ffffff" label="Designers">White</option>
    <option value="string:000000" label="HR">Black</option>
</select>
```

why the option value contains the data type such as  **number:1** or **string:ffffff** ??

how I can remove the data type from it and keeping only the value ?

Comment: could you create a plunkr of the same?

Comment: Why do you care? You shouldn't mess with the DOM anyway. What matters is what your model (i.e. $scope.user and $scope.color) contains

Comment: I'm reading it from Json array like [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ahmed"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jon"
    }
]

Answer (score 5):

Add `track by [id]` at the end of `ng-options`.

In your case it would be:

```
ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users track by user.id"
```

and

```
ng-options="color.code as color.name for color in colors track by color.code"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is not option in angular to remove that type. If you need that, use custom directive with ng-option as parent.

Comment: can you send to me example please :)

Comment: May i know why u need that option, Is it must or not??